# Calculating wattage of electrical appliances

Tags: power, watts, appliances

I need some help from you. I don't know how to calculate wattage of my refrigerator. It has a warmer part and cooler part. Below is its configuration.
[image: polytron phcm-02 configuration]

Also, if you guys don't mind, please roughly explain me on calculation of wattage of various electrical appliances. Or please share some pdfs on this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the label state, the lamp is a 15 W lamp, and the heaters total 120 W.

The refrigerator section is powered by a motor. These tend to have a poor power factor, so its consumption is given by the current, rather than the power. If it takes 0.7 A at 220 V, that's a VA of 154, so you would expect the power consumption to be some fraction of that, maybe 70 to 100 W.

The total power consumption will be the sum of whichever elements are on. In cooling duty, the cooler will cycle on and off. It's not clear what the heaters are doing, or when the controller will turn them on. You would have to observe the power consumption in any given ambient temperature to see what it actually is.